# Inheriting class attribute with double underscore

Tags: python, inheritance

I think I understand the concept of "name mangling" in python, but there's something that I probably missed. Take a look at the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Base(object):
    __data = "Base"

    @classmethod
    def func(cls):
        return "Class name is {}, data is {}".format(cls.__name__, cls.__data)


class A(Base):
    __data = "A"


class B(A):
    __data = "B"


print Base.func()
print A.func()
print B.func()
```

Here the output I get:

```
Class name is Base, data is Base
Class name is A, data is Base
Class name is B, data is Base
```

Now, I understand that for each class the actual name of the class attribute is mangled to `_<Class name>__data`. So for instance, for Base it would be `_Base__data`, for A it would be `_A__data`, etc.

My question is, inside `func` it identifies correctly the names of the inherited classes (Base, A and B), but `cls.__data` always leads to `cls._Base__data`. Why is that? I mean, if `__name__` is A or B, then I know I'm inside class A or B, so I expect `cls.__data` to be the one of A or B respectively. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing that that's exactly what it's **supposed** to do. Within methods on base, it will *always* get mangled with `'_Base'`, to *avoid* conflicts with the subclass attributes of the same name.

Answer (score 6):

You are not "missing", to the contrary, you just "found out" what name mangling does: it is made to ensure variables with double underscores inside a method will always see the attribute defined in the same class as that method, and in none of its subclasses.

If you simply want to use the attribute as it is overriden in each subclass, that is the normal behavior for all other attributes, but for the ones prefixed by two underscores.

So, what happens is that the `.__data` name used inside `func` is itself mangled, at compile time, to `_base__data`.

**OrderedDict**

Python's collections.OrderedDict have an extra trap: Python offers both a pure-python implementation, which uses the `__` for its "private attributes", as explained above, but also have a native code implementation in C, and the private structures of that are not exposed to Python.

And the `collections` module ends the  OrderedDict code block with these lines:

```py
try:
    from _collections import OrderedDict
except ImportError:
    # Leave the pure Python version in place.
    pass
```

That is: the normal "collections.OrderedDict" is written in C, with a lot of opaque structures, that can't be tapped in by subclasses.

The only way to have access to the Python defined OrderedDict is by
deleting the `_collections.OrderedDict` attribute (in the `_collections`, not `collections` module), and reload the `collections` module.

If you do that, and instantiate one ordered dict, the private data structures can be seem:

```py
from imp import reload
import _collections, collections
backup = _collections.OrderedDict
del _collections.OrderedDict
collections = reload(collections)
PyOrderedDict = collections.OrderedDict
_collections.OrderedDict = backup
a  = PyOrderedDict()
dir(a)

Out[xx]: 
['_OrderedDict__hardroot',
 '_OrderedDict__map',
 '_OrderedDict__marker',
 '_OrderedDict__root',
 '_OrderedDict__update',
 '__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 ...
]
```

Comment: So how do you **use** it in an overridden method? Do you have to create a separate attribute in the subclass and assig the *super's* mangled attribute to it?

Comment: double underscores and their name mangling are widelly misused as "private attributes", and mislisted as so in a lot of unofficial documentation. If you need to access a name-mangled attribute from a subclass, you are doing it wrong in the first place - it should not have been a double-underscore attribute.But all you need to do is to write the full mangled-name of the attribute to get to it.

Comment: Thnx, I was/am trying to subclass collections.OrderedDict and there are a lot of *mangled* attributes. If I can't figure it out I'll ask a question.

Comment: with a simple (dir) on an instantiated OrderedDict, you can see the mangled attributes final name, and, if you know what you are doing, you can access those directly.

Comment: That's what I thought yet when I tried that I don't see any mangled names. I tried using what I thought the final mangled name should be (using the base class) but that didn't work. I solved it by just copying the Whole class from the source and making the changes. I thought I was over it but now you brought it up again and I got curious again. ... Maybe the `if you know what you are doing` part applies here.

Comment: Ok - OrderedDict has a trap - the default class is written in C. I updated the answer with a way to have access to the class written in Python

Comment: Thnx  - I was starting to suspect that.

Answer (score 1):

As you have noticed, the name used for name mangling is the name of the class where a method is *declared*, not the derived type of the current object.

[The documentation for this feature](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables) explicitly gives an example about protecting a variable from a derived class (rather than from external code using an instance variable).

> Name mangling is helpful for letting subclasses override methods without breaking intraclass method calls. For example:
>
> ```
> class Mapping:
>     def __init__(self, iterable):
>         self.items_list = []
>         self.__update(iterable)
>
>     def update(self, iterable):
>         for item in iterable:
>             self.items_list.append(item)
>
>     __update = update   # private copy of original update() method
>
> class MappingSubclass(Mapping):
>
>     def update(self, keys, values):
>         # provides new signature for update()
>         # but does not break __init__()
>         for item in zip(keys, values):
>             self.items_list.append(item)
> ```